# MySQL - performance issues with "Group by"

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, web-crawler, filesort

I have a table which stores a list of URIs to be crawled. This 'crawl_index' table schema is :

```
CREATE TABLE `crawl_index` (
  `id`                INTEGER(10)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uri`               TEXT         NOT NULL,
  `domain`            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_crawled_date` INTEGER(10)  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `crawler_INDEX_1` (`domain`),
  INDEX `crawler_INDEX_2` (`last_crawled_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Some details about this table :

- it contains about 1M rows.
- nearly 60% of rows have a "last_crawled_date" set to 0 (it is quicker to extract URIs from a crawled page than actually crawling a page).
- the "id" field is never used. I only add it to the schema to have an explicit primary_key since I could not create a primary key on "uri" field since it is an unbound text.

What I want to do is to select N rows with the following constraints :

- the URI should not have been already crawled in the last 2 days
- I don't want all returned URIs to come from the same domain to avoid doing too much requests on the same domain at the same time.

For the moment, I tried this query :

```
select * from crawl_index where last_crawled_date <= 1373273029 group by domain limit 3;
```

It gives me this kind of result :

```
+--------+------------------------+--------------+-------------------+
| id     | uri                    | domain       | last_crawled_date |
+--------+------------------------+--------------+-------------------+
|  60239 | http://example1.com/1  | example1.com |                 0 |
|    239 | http://example2.com/1  | example2.com |                 0 |
| 120239 | http://example3.com/1  | example3.com |                 0 |
+--------+------------------------+--------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (1,23 sec)
```

It works but it's quite slow compared to the same query without the "group by" statement. When I run `explain` on that query, I got this :

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | crawl_index | range | crawler_INDEX_1 | crawler_INDEX_2 | 4       | NULL | 71588 | Using index condition |
|    |             |             |       | crawler_INDEX_2 |                 |         |      |       | Using temporary       |
|    |             |             |       |                 |                 |         |      |       | Using filesort        |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
```

I already :

- create indexes on last_crawled_date and domain fields
- uses integer to store my last_crawled_date to avoid datetime comparisons
- pre-calculates the max_date in my PHP code to avoid asking mysql to do that for me.

Any idea of I could improve this query ?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a composite index on (last_crawled_date, domain) and see the explain plan. It should reduce the execution time. Remove the other indexes also and test.

Answer (score 0):

> Using filesort

This is the problem. You may increase memory limit for the DB engine you use.

The other solution is: maybe you can use `ENUM` on the domain column instead of `VARCHAR(255)`?

Comment: Using `ENUM` does not seem possible as it would reuqire to update the schema each time we want to add a new domain to crawl. Increase memory limit is a good idea. I'll test it and will tell you if it has increased performances. But for now, Im' trying to understand why suddently the explain is telling me that it is no more using "filesort", "temporary" and "index" anymore but just "where"... Only change I made was to add a few hundred of thousands uris in my table to simulate production constraints. Response time remains basically the same : between 1.5 and 2 secondes. Strange...